# Нужна помощь в написании кода, я совсем новичок в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Нужно написать функцию генератор массива случайных чисел. Функция принимает несколько параметров: 1. длинна массива;
2. диапазон от n до m(Числа m и n формируют диапазон, в пределах которого должно сгенерироваться числа для массива, m и n включительно, нужно учесть, что n и m могут быть отрицательными, а также может быть n > m или n < m.);
3. строки 'even' и 'odd', (если функция получает 'even', то функция возвращает массив чётных чисел, если функция получает 'odd', то функция возвращает массив нечётных чисел).

Пока у меня получилось так, никак не могу понять как добавить строки 'even' и 'odd'

```js
function generateRandomArray(n, m, count, parity) {
  const result = [];
  const range = Math.abs(m - n) + 1;
  const min = Math.min(n, m);
  const max = Math.max(n, m);
  let i = 0;

  while (i < count) {
    i++;
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + min;
    result.push(randomNum);

  }
  return result;
}
console.log(generateRandomArray(10, 100, 50));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить фильтр по модулю через if / else:

```js
function generateRandomArray(n, m, count, parity) {
  const result = [];
  const range = Math.abs(m - n) + 1;
  const min = Math.min(n, m);
  const max = Math.max(n, m);

  while (result.length < count) {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + min;

    // Проверяем parity и фильтруем числа в зависимости от значения
    if (parity === 'even' && randomNum % 2 === 0) {
      result.push(randomNum);
    } else if (parity === 'odd' && randomNum % 2 !== 0) {
      result.push(randomNum);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(generateRandomArray(10, 100, 50, 'even'));
console.log(generateRandomArray(-50, 50, 30, 'odd'));
```

Comment: В твоем примере генерится явно не 50 или 30 элементов массива. ;)

Comment: @ksa мда, действительно надо внимательнее быть, я остальную часть кода не менял  Теперь всё тип-топ, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> никак не могу понять как добавить строки 'even' и 'odd'

Предложу такой вариант реализации этого "модификатора"...

```js
function generateRandomArray(n, m, count, parity) {
  if (parity && !['even', 'odd'].includes(parity)) return []
  const result = [];
  const range = Math.abs(m - n) + 1;
  const min = Math.min(n, m);
  const max = Math.max(n, m);

  while (result.length < count) {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + min;
    if (parity) {
      const v = randomNum % 2
      if (parity === 'even' && v) continue
      if (parity === 'odd' && !v) continue
    }
    result.push(randomNum);

  }
  return result;
}
console.log(generateRandomArray(10, 100, 5, 123));
console.log(generateRandomArray(1, 4, 5, 'even'));
console.log(generateRandomArray(10, 100, 5, 'even'));
console.log(generateRandomArray(10, 100, 5, 'odd'));
```

Answer (score 1):

В коде, который вы предоставили, нет учета параметра parity для генерации массива четных или нечетных чисел. Вот исправленная версия функции `generateRandomArray()` с учетом параметра `parity`:

В этой функции мы добавляем проверку на четность/нечетность случайно сгенерированных чисел. Если число является четным и parity равно "even", или число является нечетным и parity равно "odd", то мы добавляем его в массив result.

```js
function generateRandomArray(length, start, end, parity) {
  const result = [];
  const range = Math.abs(end - start) + 1;
  const min = Math.min(start, end);
  const max = Math.max(start, end);

  while (result.length < length) {
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + min;
    if ((randomNum % 2 === 0 && parity === 'even') || (randomNum % 2 === 1 && parity === 'odd')) {
      result.push(randomNum);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(generateRandomArray(10, -5, 5, 'even'));
console.log(generateRandomArray(5, 1, 10, 'odd'));
```

Пример использования функции:

```
console.log(generateRandomArray(10, -5, 5, 'even'));  // [4, -4, 4, -4, -2]
console.log(generateRandomArray(5, 1, 10, 'odd'));    // [1, 9, 5, 5]
```

Comment: Пробуй запустить вот так `generateRandomArray(1, 5, 5, 'even')` ;)

Comment: Хотя - отбой. В задаче не требуется уникальности чисел... :)

Answer (score 1):

Не изучал javascript, но могу подсказать:

Чтобы определить чётное число или нет, надо проверить какой остаток у этого числа при делении этого числа на 2:

- Если остаток равен нулю - число чётное (т. к. любое чётное число можно нацело разделить на 2)
- Если остаток любой другой - не чётное

Итак код должен быть примерно такой так:

1. Получаем остаток числа randomNum
2. Если в функции указан "even" и остаток равен нулю: добавляем randomNum в массив
3. Если в функции указан "odd" и остаток НЕ равен нулю: добавляем randomNum в массив